# Fork inside for-loop, too many processes made

Tags: c, process, fork

Ive run into a problem, im kinda new to ubuntu, and C for that matter, but I dont think this is going to be too hard to solve.

So this is my problem: I ask the user to enter the amount of processes he/she wants to create, and then I create them inside the for-loop, but too many processes are created!

And I know the reason, its because the child will continue executing the for-loop because the arguments for continuing the for-loop is still valid, but I dont know how to solve it.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PROGRAM_A "./loops"

int main(){
int nrOfProcesses = 1;
int i;
printf("How many processes you want to create?");
scanf("%d", &nrOfProcesses);
printf("You entered: %d\n", nrOfProcesses);
int processid;
for (i=0; i<nrOfProcesses; i++){
    if((processid = fork()) == 0){
        printf("PROCESS ID: %d\n", processid);
        pid_t pid = fork();
        printf("My PID: %d\n", (int) getpid());
        printf("Return value: %d\n", (int) pid);
    }

}
scanf("%d", &nrOfProcesses);
printf("\nProcesses created!");
execlp(PROGRAM_A,PROGRAM_A,NULL);


return 0;
}
```

And this is the outputs;

```
How many processes you want to create?2
You entered: 2
PROCESS ID: 0
My PID: 4289
Return value: 4290
PROCESS ID: 0
My PID: 4288
Return value: 4291
My PID: 4290
Return value: 0
PROCESS ID: 0
My PID: 4292
Return value: 4293
My PID: 4291
Return value: 0
My PID: 4293
Return value: 0
PROCESS ID: 0
My PID: 4294
Return value: 4295
My PID: 4295
Return value: 0
```

For clarification: I want the motherprogram (this) to create x (nrOfProcesses) numbers of processes, and not wait for them, but my program creates 4 processes instead of 2, when entering 2 as nrOfProcesses.

Comment: Why do you call `fork()` twice again inside the `if` statement?

Comment: In the child processes, just do what you are supposed to do, then `exit()`. Or call e.g. `execlp()` which won't return (unless there's an error).

Comment: Also, I really hope the program you show in your question is not this `./loops` program you execute, or you will have an endless loop fork-bombing your system.

Comment: Sorry, that was just something I was testing .. But the purpose of this exercise is to fork-bomb the system, dont ask me why tho...

Anyways, the "loops" program shall loop endlessly, so how can I solve it, so that the correct amount of processes are created ?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop creating too many processes.

- Don't call `fork()` unless you want to create another process.
- Exit the child processes created to avoid creating extra processes.
- `wait`ing the child processes to exit is a good practice.

A code with this modification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PROGRAM_A "./loops"

int main(){
    int nrOfProcesses = 1;
    int i;
    printf("How many processes you want to create?");
    scanf("%d", &nrOfProcesses);
    printf("You entered: %d\n", nrOfProcesses);
    int processid;
    for (i=0; i<nrOfProcesses; i++){
        if((processid = fork()) == 0){
            printf("PROCESS ID: %d\n", processid);
            printf("My PID: %d\n", (int) getpid());
            printf("Return value: %d\n", (int) processid);
            exit(0); /* exit this (child) process */
        }

    }
    while(wait(&i)>=0); /* get rid of the exited processes from the system */
    scanf("%d", &nrOfProcesses);
    printf("\nProcesses created!");
    execlp(PROGRAM_A,PROGRAM_A,NULL);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The purpose is not to wait till the child is finished!

I want to have 5 endles loops going on simuntaniously...

Comment: Then, do the endles loops or use `execlp` as @JoachimPileborg says instead of the exit(0);`

Comment: I do call execlp at the bottom of the code, but you dont understand my problem, too many processes are created....